# How to get all items from a complex json object

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I have some basic code which doesnt properly loop throug all the results when i use
ng-repeat in ionic to loop through my json data.

This is my html:

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item class="item-avatar-left" ng-repeat="document in documents">
       <img ng-src="{{ document.icon }}" alt="Icon">
       <h2>{{ document.title }}</h2>
       <p>{{ document.details }}</p>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This is my controller

```
$scope.getDocuments = function( user_id ) {
    // some servcie which returns a collection of documents.
    DataStorage.getAllUserDocuments( user_id ).then( function( res ) {
        console.log( res );

        if ( res.data == 0 || res.data == nulll ) {
            // do something ...
        }
        else {
            $scope.documents = res.data
        }
    })
}
```

What actually happens is that this only displays just one document (the first one) instead of 26 of them
I have tried doing this:

```
$scope.documents = res.data[0];
```

Still to no avail. How do i get all the documents to be displayed.
When the view the console.log( res ) above.
The data contains all the documents but their all wrapped in an object.

something like this:
data:

```
  Object -> contains all the documents data, i.e, ID, Title, Details, Size, Type etc.
  Object -> same here
  Object -> same here.
```

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Have you tried  `$scope.documents = angular.fromJson(res.data);` ?

Comment: Can you show exactly the returned data?

Comment: Have you tried printing the document as json? Like this: `<pre>{{document|json}}</pre>` (inside the ng-repeat)